# Как получить подробную информацию об ошибке?

Tags: ubuntu, node.js

обновил NodeJS до v.8 и получил ошибку в проекте, как найти место где она возникла?

можно ли получить стэк вызовов приведших к ошибке?

> (node:1992) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: console.table is not a function
>
> (node:1992) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: найдите в проекте все await  и оберните в try catch.

Comment: нет у меня `await` везде `Promise`

Comment: А в nodejs нет console.table. Ищите по проекту `console.table` и обрящете. А всем promisам понатыкайте `catch`